# Forcing the MPI rank 0 on the head node in a HPC Pack 2019 cluster

Tags: mpi, hpc

I have a simple MPI program (coded in C++) that needs to be run on each cluster node. However, I need the head node to have rank 0 (that's non-negotiable), and the scheduler assigns ranks somewhat randomly.

Is there a way to use the XML job file to force the head node to have rank 0 (I don't care which ranks are attributed to the other nodes)?

Here's an example of the jobfile I'm using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Job Version="3.000" Id="96" State="Configuring" CreateTime="27/12/2023 17:59:40" Name="MPI_test" IsExclusive="false" RunUntilCanceled="false" UnitType="Node" Owner="pipi" UserName="" Project="CFEA_cluster" JobType="Batch" JobTemplate="Default" Priority="Normal" OrderBy="" RequeueCount="0" AutoRequeueCount="0" PendingReason="None" AutoCalculateMax="false" AutoCalculateMin="false" FailOnTaskFailure="false" Progress="0" ProgressMessage="" MinNodes="4" MaxNodes="4" NotifyOnStart="false" NotifyOnCompletion="false" JobValidExitCodes="0" ParentJobIds="" EstimatedProcessMemory="0" TaskExecutionFailureRetryLimit="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/HPCS2008R2/scheduler/">
    <Dependencies />
    <Tasks>
        <Task Version="3.000" Id="91" ParentJobId="96" RequiredNodes="CLUSTER-NODEH" State="Configuring" UnitType="Node" WorkDirectory="\\CLUSTER-NODEH\MPIShared" NiceId="1" CommandLine="mpiexec MPI_tests.exe" StdOutFilePath="out.txt" StdErrFilePath="err.txt" RequeueCount="0" PendingReason="None" StartValue="0" EndValue="0" IncrementValue="1" GroupId="98" CreateTime="27/12/2023 17:59:40" Name="My Task" MinNodes="4" MaxNodes="4" AutoRequeueCount="0" Type="Basic" FailJobOnFailure="false" />
    </Tasks>
</Job>
```

Comment: I do not know `HPC Pack 2019 cluster`. FWIW, MPI applications should not use `MPI_COMM_WORLD` directly, but a user specified communicator. If your application already does this, you can build this communicator from `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, for example with `MPI_Comm_split()` to have rank `0` on the head node. That of course assumes the head node is part of the allocated nodes.